# WebKit support lower version of iOS

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, margins

I am trying to add webView inside my Application.

In low version of iOS the webView is behind the status bar.In iOS 11 and above webView is positioned correctly.Why it is not positioned correctly in lower version of iOS? 
How to add space between webView and status bar that support for all iOS devices?

Here is my code

```
override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView  
}
```

I tried to add margin and top constraint.It doesn't work.

```
  let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
  webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor,constant : 200).isActive = true
  view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 164, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Hope you understand my problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to position my webpage:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
    {
        allStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    else
    {
        allStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    }
}
```

where ***allStack*** is the UIStackView that holds my custom navigation bar and the WKWebView.

This position the entire view 20 point from the top if less than iOS 11, otherwise it islet to the safe area.